# apply and sum values based on the range

Tags: sql

Table info: I have to apply progressive charges based on the volume using sql query

Transaction volume =49

```
Code |Serial num |Value_from|Value_To|Price
111  |1          |1         |20      |3
111  |2          |21        |40      |2
111  |3          |41        |9999    |1
```

first 20 transactions - 20 * 3 
next tier :20 * 2
Last - 9 * 1
SUM(20 * 3,20 * 2 ,9 * 1)

How can this be achieved using SQL

Comment: Can you show us what you've come up so far?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support `least()` and `greatest()`, so I'll use one of those functions.  It is easy to replace the logic with a `case` expression.

```
select sum( (least(value_to, 49) - value_to + 1) * price ) as total_price
from t
where code = 111 and 49 >= value_from;
```

Of course, you would replace the `49` with whatever your actual quantity is.

Answer (score 0):

You already know you want the sum of separate calculations. One of these is 20 * 2 (with 2 being the price). Now, just think about why it is 20 * 2. It is, because `value_to` 40 is not greater than 49, so you consider this range and 20 results from `value_to - value_from + 1`.

In order to to proof-read: You want the sum of

```
(20 -  1 + 1) * 3   because 20 <= 49
(40 - 21 + 1) * 2   because 40 <= 49
(49 - 41 + 1) * 1   because 9999 > 49, but 41 <= 49
```

You need to check the ranges against the given value (49 in your case), for which you need an IF/THEN construct. IF/THEN is `CASE WHEN ... THEN` in SQL.

```
select
  sum
  (
    case
      when value_to <= given.value then (value_to - value_from + 1) * price
      when value_from <= given.value then (given.value - value_from + 1) * price
    end
  ) as total_price
from (select 49 as value) given
cross join ranges;
```